# 'Log4j.properties' not found when exporting maven project into a Runnable Jar (JAVA, Eclipse)

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, executable-jar

I have exported a maven project into a 'Runnable jar file' using eclipse. In the resources folder, I have the images and 'log4j.properties' with the 'log4j.log'. The application fills the 'log4j.log' with the info needed and prints it to the user in a frame. When I export the application as a jar file, it is not able to get the 'log4.properties' any more.

```
    log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
   ERROR Could not read configuration file "file:/C:/Users/R/Desktop/APP.jar!/log4j.properties "
```

But there is an exclamation mark '!' in the file path, after the App.jar. It might be causing the problem. How can I remove it?

Also, I tried to use this function:

```
        URL url =getClass().getResource("/log4j.properties");
```

But it is not working with  the 'log4j.properties' file. However, when I use it with images it is working fine!!

How can get the log4j.properties file when exporting a maven java application into a jar file?

Comment: Are you including `log4j.properties` in your executable jar?  Can you run `jar tvf myapp.jar` and confirm that the file is included?

Comment: yes, I have  zipped the jar file and it was there. But I noticed that there is exclamation mark '!' in the file path. The error showing : ERROR Could not read configuration file "file:/C:/Users/R/Desktop/APP.jar!/log4j.properties ". How can I remove this??

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow.  Can you post the output of `jar tvf APP.jar` here?

Comment: When i use this command, I am getting: " 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. ". But the log4.properties is in the excutable jar because when I zip the jar file into a folder, it shows the 'log4j.properties'